# Updgrading database downloading it from a server

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an app that creates a database and do some stuff. I am wondering if i upload a new db to a server and download it to the exact folder where the older one exists it will be overwritten and i am good to go? Or there will be a problem. Assuming it has the same name, same column names, etc. Of course i am reffering to sqlite.

Comment: yes sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: This should work but remember to close all database objects before you replace the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, when performing a database update you should be using [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) inside of the SQLiteOpenHelper. One way of doing this is to download text files that include the sql instructions needed to modify the current database or update rows with new data. The reason you have to do this is because Android will only create the database once. After the initial creation the call to onCreate for the database will not occur.

Comment: We'll the idea of what you are wanting to do can be accomplished using the method above. You might have to alter your execution but it should be doable to update the database by checking a remote file.

Comment: But the remote file could not a sqlite file itself? Or just like u said a text file with the sql statement?